# Find text and replace with image in Jquery for multiple text instances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple pieces of text that need replacement on a page to corresponding images.

I have this code:

```
$('.icon-box-1').each(function() {
var text = $(this).text();
$(this).html(text.replace('1', '<img  src="1.png"  alt=""  />'));
$(this).html(text.replace('2', '<img  src="2.png"  alt=""  />'));
$(this).html(text.replace('3', '<img  src="3.png"  alt=""  />'));
});
```

Unfortunately it only replaces 1 of the 3. How do i get it to update all 3?

Thanks

Comment: update the text variable with the replacements, and call .html once with the updated text

Answer (score 0):

You want to update `text` with each replacement, then call `.html()` with `text`, which then has all of the replacements:

```
$('.icon-box-1').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text()
    .replace('1', '<img  src="1.png"  alt=""  />')
    .replace('2', '<img  src="2.png"  alt=""  />')
    .replace('3', '<img  src="3.png"  alt=""  />');

  $(this).html(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qp78rdzo/

```
$('.icon-box-1').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();

    text = text.replace('1', '<img  src="1.png"  alt="">');
    text = text.replace('2', '<img  src="2.png"  alt="">');
    text = text.replace('3', '<img  src="3.png"  alt="">');

    $(this).html(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the text to be replaced is always an integer and always matches the filename of the image, then you can make the code a one-liner using an arrow function and a regular expression:

```js
$('.icon-box-1').html((_, h) => h.replace(/(\d)/g, '<img src="$1.png" alt="$1" />'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-box-1">This is 1</div>
<div class="icon-box-1">This is 2</div>
<div class="icon-box-1">This is 3</div>
<div class="icon-box-1">This is 1 and 2</div>
<div class="icon-box-1">This is 2 and 3</div>
<div class="icon-box-1">This is 3 and 1</div>
```